# Change Users Variables using compiler directive?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How can I change a user variable like $(Test) via code, using a compiler directive or via project options?

I have defined this variable that sometimes points to a trunk svn source code and sometimes it points to a tag svn source. I use this var in Library Path. When I open the trunk project i need the var to be set to the trunk svn source and when i open the tag svn project i need the var to be set to the tag svn. Both projects in the trunk and tag are the same, but the trunk has some modifications (it is the code i am working at and it is not ready to be used yet).

**I do not** want to go to the Tools options to set it every time i change projects.

**EDIT:**

I know I could use the project source path instead of the library path, but I need all sources to be on library path so I can easily debug a project that is using my framework.

Comment: You're not really clear what you're trying to do here. `$(Test)` refers to an environmental variable named `Test`, and has absolutely nothing to do with the compiler; it's used by the IDE to resolve paths (directories) at compile time. A compiler define wouldn't do anything to change the environment. Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: i don't know about using a compiler directive to do this. but if you wanna another method here is: first you must note which these variables are available only when you run your app under the delphi ide,  now you can read these variables using the `GetEnvironmentVariable` function and set the value using the `SetEnvironmentVariable` , so you can write something like this in your code `SetEnvironmentVariable('Test','C:\');`

Comment: Edited to clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. You should have two separate project files (.dproj), and open the one in the IDE you're wanting to work with. Each project configuration file maintains it's own path info. The only thing that would differ is the .dproj, and you don't check that in to your VCS. That way when you check code in/out of each branch, it keeps it's own copy of the .dproj with the right path configurations. (I only check in .dfm, .dpr, .pas, .rc (resource) source for my own resources, and any images that are project-specific or included in the mentioned resources.)

Comment: Yeah, agreed. But I have some projects which uses my framework. When something goes wrong with hose projects I want to be able to debug them and my framework. If I dont have the library path for each trunk and tag, I will not be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably create two batch files. Each would first set the `Test` environmental variable to the necessary value, then start the IDE.

And then every time I needed to work with a different set of svn source files I'd have to (re)start the IDE through the appropriate batch file.

Comment: That's what we do, it seems to be the least awful option. For a while we had an exe that edited the dof files supposedly in a generic way, but it broke so often it was more hassle than it was worth. Better to have a human do it and possibly a script check it.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to the question is: That is not possible!

But may be this is a solution to the problem: You can have special build configurations to handle your specific request. Perhaps you can use an optionset on an existing build configuration to establish the correct pathes.